# EmailID with semicolun in single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT email_id from A;
```

gives me

A@g.com
    b@g.com
    c@g.com

I want the output  in single row

```
A@g.com;b@g.com;c@g.com
```

Comment: Select stuff((Select ';'+nc_user_email from  dbo.view_nc_user_info_login where nc_user_role_id IN (5,6) for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Email_ID

Comment: Above is the Answer I did some changes

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Stuff((Select ','+EmailColumnName from TableName for Xml Path('')),1,1,'');
```

or If u have Email Already in On Row than,,,

```
Select Replace(EmailColumnName,' ',';') from TableName
```

Comment: Thanks Amit but both are not working. First giving error in For stat Can u give me one combined query

Comment: Select stuff((Select ';'+nc_user_email from  dbo.view_nc_user_info_login where nc_user_role_id IN (5,6) for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as Email_ID
Thanks Amit

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @myString as NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

SELECT @myString = @myString + CASE WHEN @myString = '' THEN '' ELSE ';' END + email_id  FROM A;

SELECT @myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(email_id SEPARATOR ';') FROM A;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: OP's running SQL-Server not MYSql

Comment: Yes, just saw that & was about to comment myself.